# WSO2 DSS 3.5.0 - DataService Task Class error

Tags: wso2, task, wso2-data-services-server

I'm currently working on WSO2 DSS 3.5.0, trying to follow this example:
https://itsmeisuru.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/wso2-dss-scheduled-task-example/

I've created the JAR file of a simple java class that implement "DataTask".
It put this JAR in the repository DSS_HOME/repository/components/lib like it's said in step 2 of the example.

Then, when I create the schedule task like in the step 6. 
I have the following error in my server console:

> INFO {org.quartz.core.JobRunShell} -  Job
>   TENANT_-1234_TYPE_DATA_SERVICE_TASK.ScheduleTest threw a
>   JobExecutionException:  org.quartz.JobExecutionException: Error in
>   executing task: Error in initializing Data Task: sample.Test cannot be
>   found by org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task_4.3.4 [See nested
>   exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in initializing Data
>   Task: sample.Test cannot be found by
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task_4.3.4]  at
>   org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:74)
>     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in initializing Data Task:
>   sample.Test cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task_4.3.4
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task.DSTaskExt.init(DSTaskExt.java:42)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:66)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Test
>   cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task_4.3.4    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task.DSTaskExt.init(DSTaskExt.java:36)
>     ... 7 more

Note that my package name is "sample" and the name of my java class is "Test".

It looks like the scheduled task doesn't retrieve the class I indicate in the field "DataService Task Class".

Has anybody already had the same problem?

I also tried to used the JAR generated in the example as it's provided in the step 2. Then I follow the very same other steps. Finally I have the same problem:

[classpath] cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task_4.3.4

Comment: I've run the same test on WSO2 DSS 3.0.1 and it worked...
It seems to be a difference the 2 versions or perhaps just a difference in a configuration file.
Still I search for an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in DSS 3.5.0. The related JIRA can be found from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1175). This is fixed and the fix will be available in the upcoming release 3.5.1. The planned date for the 3.5.1 release is mid of July 2016. Please note that this can be changed due to certain circumstances.